# List data not found when validation failed in struts2

Tags: java, validation, jsp, combobox, struts2

I am new to the Struts and I have to add a module to existing system using struts2 with annotation. I must have to use struts 2.3.34 version with JDK6.

I have messed up the struts2 validations. The issue is that my form contains a `<s:select />`, when the validation fails, the server complains that no collection or list found for that `<s:select />`. If I remove that tag, the validations work fine.

My code snippet is as follows:
(JSP)

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Enter Violation Number<h2>

<s:form method="post" action="searchViolation" namespace="/Broker">
    <s:textfield name="violationNumber" label="Name" maxlength="10"/>
    <s:submit value="Search" name="submit" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Backing Java class:

```
@Namespace("/Broker")
@ResultPath(value = "/")
@Results({
    @Result(name = "success", location = "pages/enter_defense.jsp"),
    @Result(name = "input", location = "pages/search_violation.jsp"),
})
@InterceptorRefs ({
    @InterceptorRef("defaultStack")
})
public class ViolationNumberAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2137861793381499464L;

    private String violationNumber;
    private static List<String> states;

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
    states = new ArrayList<String>();
    states.add("New York");
    }

    @Action(value = "searchViolation")
    public String execute() {

    return SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * @return the violationNumber
     */
    @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName="violationNumber", message="Violation Number is rquired.", trim=true)
    public String getViolationNumber() {
    return violationNumber;
    }
```

The next JSP where view is forwarded if violation number is not null is as follows:

```
<s:form method="post" action="create_hearing" namespace="/Broker">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><s:textfield name="firstName" label="First Name"
                    labelposition="top" maxlength="30" errorPosition="top" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><s:textfield name="address" label="Address"
                    labelposition="top" maxlength="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <s:select
                    label="State/Province" value="state" name="states"
                    labelposition="top" headerValue="--- Please Select ---"
                    headerKey="1" list="states" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><s:submit value="Continue" name="submit"
                    onclick="validate()" /></td>
            <td><s:submit value="Cancel" name="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</s:form>
```

And hence, the backing java class is as under:

```
@Namespace("/Broker")
@ResultPath(value = "/")
@Results({
    @Result(name = "success", location = "pages/verify_info.jsp"),
    @Result(name = "input", location = "Broker/pages/enter_defense.jsp"),
})
@InterceptorRefs ({
    @InterceptorRef("defaultStack"), 
    @InterceptorRef("prepare")
})
public class CreateNewHearingAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5864237156298942117L;

    private String firstName;
    private String address;
    private String state;

    @Action(value = "/create_hearing")
    @InputConfig(methodName="input")
    public String execute() {

    return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String state() throws Exception {
    return SUCCESS;
    }
```

The issue is that when the validation fails, the following error is displayed:

```
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages:   
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'states': The requested list key 'states' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name}
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'states': The requested list key 'states' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
File:   org/apache/jasper/servlet/JspServletWrapper.java
Line number:    480
```

Any suggestions/solution please?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/How+do+we+repopulate+controls+when+validation+fails

Comment: You will have *a lot* of problems in your programming life by *not* indenting the code like this :S

Comment: @Roman C following the link you mentioned above, I have duplicated the states list to both ViolationNumberAction and CreateNewHearingAction and implemented Preparable interface there too. It's now working but this is not a good approach and also the list is expensive to populate.
In fact, when I remove states list from ViolationNumberAction, struts doesn't find the list in that case. It's really a headache.

Comment: @ahmarhashmi You should upvote that link because it helped you to move further.

Comment: @Roman, I have upvoted that. Thanks.